# Compute uniswap pair address via python

Tags: python, hex, solidity, web3py, uniswap

I`m trying to compute (off-line, i.e. without an http requests) address of an Uniswap pair,
with python, web3 and eth-abi libraries, based on [this](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contract-integration/getting-pair-addresses/) solidity
example.

```
address factory = 0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f;
address token0 = 0xCAFE000000000000000000000000000000000000; // change me!
address token1 = 0xF00D000000000000000000000000000000000000; // change me!

address pair = address(uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
  hex'ff',
  factory,
  keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1)),
  hex'96e8ac4277198ff8b6f785478aa9a39f403cb768dd02cbee326c3e7da348845f'
))));
```

Have some thoughts:

```
hexadem_ ='0x96e8ac4277198ff8b6f785478aa9a39f403cb768dd02cbee326c3e7da348845f'
hexadem_1 = 0xff
abiEncoded_1 = encode_abi_packed(['address', 'address'], (  token_0, token_1 ))
salt_ = web3.Web3.solidityKeccak(['bytes'], ['0x' +abiEncoded_1.hex()])
abiEncoded_2 = encode_abi_packed(['bytes', 'address', 'bytes32'], (bytes(hexadem_1), factory, salt_))
resPair = web3.Web3.solidityKeccak(['bytes','bytes'], ['0x' +abiEncoded_2.hex(), hexadem_])
```

Can somebody suggest me, what is wrong, which way it should be considered?

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, resPair is too long to be a contract address.
The rules can be explained by reading this: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1014

Also make sure you enter the two addresses in alphabetical order. Use the .sort() function to do this.

Here is the correct code:

```
hexadem_ ='0x96e8ac4277198ff8b6f785478aa9a39f403cb768dd02cbee326c3e7da348845f'
hexadem_1 = 0xff
factory = '0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f' 
abiEncoded_1 = encode_abi_packed(['address', 'address'], ('0x7825e833d495f3d1c28872415a4aee339d26ac88', '0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2' )) #these two addresses to be changed as fit. Currently they are TLOS and WETH
salt_ = w3.solidityKeccak(['bytes'], ['0x' +abiEncoded_1.hex()])
abiEncoded_2 = encode_abi_packed([ 'address', 'bytes32'], ( factory, salt_))
resPair = w3.solidityKeccak(['bytes','bytes'], ['0xff' + abiEncoded_2.hex(), hexadem_])[12:]
resPair
```

Comment: Hello. What about reverse computing? Get tokens from pair.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong `hexadem_`
Use this one:

`hexadem_ = 0x00fb7f630766e6a796048ea87d01acd3068e8ff67d078148a3fa3f4a84f69bd5`

See line 298 in the contract source of PancakeRouter
https://bscscan.com/address/0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E#code

Comment: you're not looking on the right network. They are on Ethereum, your answer is for BSC. The address they used is for Uniswap V2: Router 2, as seen on line 700 here: https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d#code