# Compute pancake pair address via python3

Tags: python-3.x, hex, solidity, binance-smart-chain

This question is quite related to [Compute uniswap pair address via python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66710238/compute-uniswap-pair-address-via-python/67156507#67156507)

I am trying to do the same but for panckage swap v2.

I am using the CAKE/WBNB pair as an example:

```
CONTRACTS = {
    "CAKE": "0x0E09FaBB73Bd3Ade0a17ECC321fD13a19e81cE82",
}

PANCAKE_SWAP_FACTORY = "0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73"
PANCAKE_SWAP_ROUTER  = "0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E"

WBNB_ADDRESS = "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c"

hexadem_ ='0x00fb7f630766e6a796048ea87d01acd3068e8ff67d078148a3fa3f4a84f69bd5'
factory = PANCAKE_SWAP_FACTORY
abiEncoded_1 = encode_abi_packed(['address', 'address'], (CONTRACTS['CAKE'], WBNB_ADDRESS))
salt_ = pancakeswap.w3.solidityKeccak(['bytes'], ['0x' +abiEncoded_1.hex()])
abiEncoded_2 = encode_abi_packed([ 'address', 'bytes32'], ( factory, salt_))

resPair = pancakeswap.w3.solidityKeccak(['bytes','bytes'], ['0xff' + abiEncoded_2.hex(), hexadem_])[12:]

# resPair is the address for the pancakeswap CAKE/WBNB pair
print(resPair.hex())
print('0xA527a61703D82139F8a06Bc30097cC9CAA2df5A6')
print(resPair.hex() == '0xA527a61703D82139F8a06Bc30097cC9CAA2df5A6')
print()
```

My first problem is the code is not working, it is not producint the correct contract address, in fact it prints:

```
0x0ed7e52944161450477ee417de9cd3a859b14fd0
0xA527a61703D82139F8a06Bc30097cC9CAA2df5A6
False
```

I think the problem is the value of the constant hexadem_, which can be found in:

- hexadem_ = '0xd0d4c4cd0848c93cb4fd1f498d7013ee6bfb25783ea21593d5834f5d250ece66' # from https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-periphery/blob/master/contracts/libraries/PancakeLibrary.sol
- hexadem_ ='0x96e8ac4277198ff8b6f785478aa9a39f403cb768dd02cbee326c3e7da348845f' # from uniswap (most likely wrong...)
- hexadem_ ='0x00fb7f630766e6a796048ea87d01acd3068e8ff67d078148a3fa3f4a84f69bd5' # from https://bscscan.com/address/0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E#code line 298

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address you obtained is correct. The address that you are attempting to match to is for pancake V1.
You can see this by clicking on "contract creator" for the 2 addresses, and you will see the pancake factory versions for 0x0ed7e52944161450477ee417de9cd3a859b14fd0 and 0xA527a61703D82139F8a06Bc30097cC9CAA2df5A6.