# How can I get pool with ETH in Uniswap v3?

Tags: ethereum, pool, uniswap

I want to get pool with ETH (ETH/UNI, ETH/USDC, ...).

I tried to call getPool() function of uniswap factory contract with 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, but it returns 0x0, which means there is no pool.

Answer (score 2):

There are no pools with ETH in Uniswap v3 (or Uniswap v2 for that matter), only pools with WETH (ERC-20 wrapped ETH). The address of the WETH token depends on the network. For the Ethereum mainnet the WETH address is [0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2](https://%20https://etherscan.io/token/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2). Use this address as an argument for the `getPool` function.

For instance, to get the UNI/WETH 0.3% pool (UNI token address is `0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984` on the mainnet), call:

```
getPool('0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984',
        '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2',
        3000)
```

Something to note: the pool addresses are deterministic and can be computed off-chain. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69472821/compute-uniswap-3-0-pool-pair-address-via-python3) for example code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Can I use the returned pool for swapping ETH -> UNI?

Comment: And how can I get access to USDC / ETH pool?

Comment: @LazaroNascimento expanded the answer.

Comment: I'll create a new question.

Comment: @kfx are you sure there is not a single eth pool on uniswap?https://info.uniswap.org/#/pools/0x88e6a0c2ddd26feeb64f039a2c41296fcb3f5640

Comment: or is that also weth and they just use the eth symbol

Comment: @MubashirWaheed they use "ETH" in the UI, but it's WETH in the code.